# What type of image filtering/processing do mobile PDF scanners use to convert a captured image into a monochrome/black and white image?

Tags: c#, pdf, image-processing

I am trying to implement my own monochrome/black and white filter in C# to scan text documents. My approach is to apply a threshold filter on the captured image. However, I often run into the problem that the varying brightness on the image causes a ''shadowing effect'' on the processed image. Refer to the link below (it is pretty blurry but it should suffice). The image to the far left is the original image. When I apply my threshold filter, I get the same result as the image in the middle; some of the text becomes unreadable because the brightness of the image varies, so some portions become really black or really white. However, with the right filter, you can obtain the processed image to the right where everything looks crystal clear.

https://www.google.dk/search?q=monochrome+image+processing&espv=2&biw=1706&bih=859&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwir8vXlhIzPAhUFiywKHeSBC1wQ_AUIBigB#imgrc=4UTzoIpyqTkwrM%3A

I would like to know what the process is to obtain the image to the far right. Another example can be seen in the image below. It shows a sample mobile PDF scanner in use. Scanning the image results in a very nice black and white image, where the text can be easily read and no ''shadowing'' occurs on the image. Does anyone know what this process is or what it is called? It is very often used in mobile PDF scanning applications. Thank you in advance.

[image]

EDIT: The filter is called ''Adaptive Thresholding''. You can use the BradleyLocalThresholding class to implement the filter, or you can write it yourself (which is what I did). Please refer to my response to the comment by Yves Daoust down below.

Comment: There is no "image in the middle".

Comment: The google image link was supposed to lead to an image that showed how a correct filter could remove the effects of a brightness gradient on a captured image. However, this link has disappeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two ingredients.

One is "background reconstruction", i.e. retrieving the intensity of the white sheet "under the characters", for instance by morphological opening.

The other is "shading correction", i.e. compensating the unevenness of the background illumination by comparing to the reconstructed background, for instance by subtraction.

This will "flatten" the image, making it perfectly amenable to global thresholding.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The filter that I was looking for is called ''Adaptive Thresholding''. However, I also wrote a morphological opening algorithm to enlarge all the filtered pixels so a clearer text could be obtained. The links below describe how to implement the filter.

Link 1:
http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/adpthrsh.htm
Link 2:
http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/0ad5b988-5613-d62a-22a9-cf41e39c139f.htm

Answer (score 0):

A simple method is to convert the image to grayscale and then convert it to B/W using an error diffusion algorithm such as Floyd–Steinberg dithering.